# Find tag with contents in HTML using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find tag `article` and all it's content in HTML string using Regex.

I can successfully match open tag with attrs: `<article[^>]*>`

I've got issues with matching contents. `(.*?)` - [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) technique is not working for me.

Please help.

Comment: Please share complete information. what issues are you getting? Why can't you use HTML parser API?

Comment: You are saying, c#, why not you are using Linq to Xml. Definitely we need more details on xml structure to answer.

Comment: It may be worth using something like HTML agility pack as this is going to be tricky to do properly with regex alone http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1149773

Comment: I am planning to use Linq2Xml when I get all necessary tags. The DOM structure of a page I am trying to parse is not parsing using XElement.Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use regular expressions to parse HTML in general. However, in constrained scenarios (i.e. when the input follows a rigid structure), you might be able to get away with it. In your case, you can use the following regex, provided that:

- The `<article>` tags are not self-closing
- The `<article>` elements do not contain other `<article>` descendants
- The strings `<article` and `</article>` do not appear as literals in your HTML.

Code:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(html, @"<article.*?</article>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```